# Dynamic instantiation of Scala Enumeration

Tags: scala, reflection, enumeration

Is there any way to dynamically instantiate an Enumeration#Value in Scala?

So far I have:

```
object Letter extends Enumeration {
    val A,B,C = Value
}

// fieldType is of type Universe.Type for the field in my case class, which happens to
// be of type Letter.Value

val ftype = fieldType.typeSymbol.name.toString
val enumVal = "B"  // a valid Enumeration.Value
val erasedEnumType = fieldType.asInstanceOf[TypeRef]  // Letter
```

Now what?  I'm trying to arrive at an object of value Letter.B in this case.

I saw this clip on another posting:

```
def create[T <: Enum[T]](clazz: Class[T], input: String): T = Enum.valueOf(clazz, input)
```

I couldn't make this work because I don't have "T" at compile-time (I'm parsing this value from input strings at runtime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean retrieve instead of instantiate?

```
scala> object Letter extends Enumeration {
     |     val A,B,C = Value
     | }
defined module Letter

scala> Letter withName "B"
res0: Letter.Value = B
```

as opposed to [creating another value](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/reporters/Reporter.scala#L22).

Updated:

```
package reflectenum

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror=>cm}
import scala.reflect.NameTransformer._

object Letters extends Enumeration {
  val A,B,C = Value
}

object Test extends App {
  val claas = cm.classLoader loadClass "reflectenum.Letters$"
  Console println s"$claas"
  val enum  = claas.getField(MODULE_INSTANCE_NAME).get(null).asInstanceOf[Enumeration]
  Console println s"$enum"
  Console println s"${enum withName "B"}"

  // given some element of the enumeration
  val v = enum withName "B"
  val im = cm reflect v
  val outerName = newTermName("scala$Enumeration$$outerEnum")
  val outer = typeOf[enum.Value] member outerName
  val f = im reflectField outer.asTerm.accessed.asTerm
  assert(enum == f.get)
}
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  How can I do that?  Remember I don't know "Letter" at compile time.  I'm parsing string input.  I can introspect as described above, so I know the type and can get to the erased type, but I'm still stuck on retrieving the Value.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
val foo = Class.forName("reflectnum.Letter$") //← note extra $
val anObj = foo.getField("MODULE$").get(foo)
val meth = anObj.getClass.getMethod("withName",classOf[String])
val z = meth.invoke(anObj,"B")
```

Comment: It's not necessary to invoke withName reflectively, see my answer. It's not clear to me what you needed, so my answer also includes a nontrivial part: given some B, the user asks for "C", how do I find the enclosing enum in order to look up C?

Comment: Right you are!  Missed something on first read, but your answer not requiring dynamic reflection of withName works great.